# Using createjs-soundjs in react web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, soundjs

I would like to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs-soundjs to play sounds on a react web app.

I installed the package normally with `npm install createjs-soundjs` and it's showing in the packages list. How should I include this to my project, so that I could use it?

I have tried the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import createjs from 'createjs';
import SoundJS from 'createjs-soundjs'; // this line causes an error
```

The error message in console: soundjs-0.6.2.min.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined. This error message is very clear, but I have no idea where to start. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Ended up using a different package https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundmanager2 which offered very pleasant developer experience. However, I would still like to know what was the issue with soundJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SoundJS core bundle is not in the proper CommonJS or ES6 format, it's a bundle that makes strong assumption that it's loaded as a top-level script in the browser. So it first tries to create the global value by assigning it to a property on `this` (which it assumes to be the window) and then tries to access this global values as just `createjs`.
So obviously this doesn't work in the module context.

There's a workaround though, the code is for Webpack 2 and based on [this comment](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/85#issuecomment-168099713) (which is for Webpack 1):

```
module: {
  rules: [
    // ...
    {
      test: /createjs/,
      use: [
        'imports-loader?this=>window',
        'exports-loader?createjs'
      ]
    },
    // ...
  ]
},

plugins: [
  // ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'createjs': 'createjs',
  }),
  // ...
],

resolve: {
  alias: {
    'createjs': path.resolve(__dirname, '../lib/soundjs-0.6.2.combined'),
  }
},
```

The 3rd entry (resolve.alias) maps the imports of `createjs` to the file I've downloaded and placed into my `lib` folder (which is not as elegant as using something from npm, but now I'm sure what I get. npm version might work as well).

The first entry (module.rules) tells Webpack to first substitute `this` with `window`, and then to take the `createjs` instance from the global (window) context and make it the module export.

Finally, the 2nd entry (ProvidePlugin) precedes all requests for global `createjs` (in other modules) with `const createjs = require('createjs')`.