# Using PreloadJS and SoundJS in React app to preload sounds

Tags: reactjs, createjs, soundjs, preloadjs

I’m trying to use PreloadJS and SoundJS in a React app to preload all sounds and then play from the preloaded cache.

I can't figure out how to create the LoadQueue and load the sounds in one component (top level: `App.jsx` ), and play them in a different component (child of `App.jsx`: `Board.jsx`).

The preloader is working fine but I can't get sounds to play in the child component. When I try to call `createjs.Sound.play()` I keep getting error messages that `createjs.Sound` is undefined. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm installing the Sound plugin in one component and then trying to access it somewhere else, but the Sound plugin seems to be attached to the LoadQueue itself and I don't think I want a new LoadQueue in the `Board` component? What am I doing wrong?

Things I have tried so far that have not worked:

1. Modifying `webpack.config` according to instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926257/using-createjs-soundjs-in-react-web-app), which is supposed to make `createjs` available in the global context
2. Defining a `playSound` method in my top-level component (where the LoadQueue is defined) and passing that method as a prop to the child component where I want to play the sound.

`asset_loader.js`

```
import createjs from 'preload-js';
import manifest from '../sounds/asset_manifest.json';

const assetLoader = () => {
  // Reset the UI
  document.getElementById('progress').style.width = '0px';

  // Create a preloader.
  const preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
  preload.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
  const assetManifest = manifest.manifest;

  // If there is an open preload queue, close it.
  if (preload != null) {
    preload.close();
  }

  // File complete handler
  const handleFileLoad = (event) => {
    console.log(`Preloaded: ${event.item.id}`);
  };

  // Overall progress handler
  const handleOverallProgress = () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = `${(preload.progress * document.getElementById('progress-wrap').clientWidth)}px`;
  };

  // Error handler
  const handleFileError = (event) => {
    console.log(`error: ${event.item.id}, ${event.text}`);
  };

  const handleComplete = () => {
    console.log('loading complete');
  };

  preload.on('fileload', handleFileLoad);
  preload.on('progress', handleOverallProgress);
  preload.on('error', handleFileError);
  preload.on('complete', handleComplete);
  preload.setMaxConnections(5);

  const loadAnother = () => {
    // Get the next manifest item, and load it
    const item = assetManifest.shift();
    preload.loadFile(item);
  };

  const loadAll = () => {
    while (assetManifest.length > 0) {
      loadAnother();
    }
  };
  loadAll();
};

export default assetLoader;
```

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

// …

import assetLoader from './utils/asset_loader';


class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    assetLoader();
  }

// …
```

`Board.jsx`

```
// …
import createjs from 'preload-js';

//…

playSound(item) {
     console.log(`playing sound: ${item}`);
     createjs.Sound.play(item);
  }
```

Error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`

Comment: When you try to play any sound file from your main class (App.jsx) after loading, it works?

Comment: @ThiagoCoelho no, it's not working. from an answer in another forum i figured out I wasn't importing Sound.js properly. I thought installing the plugin took care of that but I now know it needs to be imported separately.

I tried importing it first using npm createjs-soundjs and then just saving Sound.js directly to my project directory. got error messages both times, which somebody suggested might be due to a version mismatch between Preload.js & Sound.js. Trying with PreloadJS: 0.6.3 and SoundJS: 1.0.1. 

How do I know which versions match?

Comment: did you see that question? Maybe it will be helpfull. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926257/using-createjs-soundjs-in-react-web-app

Also I'm seeing that both preloadjs and soundjs are in the same version 0.6.3, theorically they should work.